# Ios Development Codename one : Populate Autocomplete using database values

Tags: ios, codenameone

how to populate Autocomplete textfield in Codename one using database values.. i tried my level best.. but no good results..

```
cr = db.executeQuery(qry);
            while(cr.next()){
                Row r = cr.getRow();
                list.add(r.getString(0));

                setArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
            }

             ((ListModel<String>) autocomplete).addItem(setArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to just past the `String[]` argument to the auto complete in the constructor. In case that isn't an option you can create your own list model and pass it there where you can fetch the data lazily.

This is discussed here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/completion-ios-7-update-and-the-20m-mark

You can override filter to perform more advanced filtering but since you generate a String array anyway it doesn't seem like you need that.